# Are there differences between the activation proteins of Eukaryotes and those of Prokaryotes

Tags: proteins, gene-expression, eukaryotic-cells, prokaryotic-cells

I'm in BIO 203 (for reference to my skill level), and I noticed the textbook makes a whole section out of transcriptional activator proteins, their function and applications in eukaryotes, but in prokaryotes the term "activator protein" is used only once when mentioning the lac operon.

Are they the same type of activator proteins? Do they employ the same mechanisms?

Answer (score -1):

In general transcription activators are transcription factors. These are very different in eukaryotes although some families share similar domains (e.g. two component signalization). I recommend you read through these two chapters to get a more complete overview on the differences.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21683/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21572/

Comment: As it stands your answer does not explain how these are different, and the two separate chapters you cite do not make such a comparison. For your answer to be useful you need to explain brielfy in what way they are different.